# On One-to-One Functions of Complete Statistics

Tags: mathematical-statistics, inference

Why is a one-to-one function of complete statistic also complete? How might you go about proving this?

Comment: Since this sounds like a course question, I suggest you add the `self-study` tag to your question.

Answer (score 3):

With those two definitions,

> **Complete statistic:** The statistic s is said to be complete for the distribution of X if for every measurable function g (which must be
>   independent of θ) the following implication holds:[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completeness_%28statistics%29)
>
> $$ \mathbb{E}_\theta[g(s(X))] = 0 \text{ for all θ implies that }P_θ(g(s(X)) = 0) = 1 \text{ for all θ.}$$
>   [[Completeness (statistics)]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completeness_%28statistics%29)

and

> **One-to-one or injective function:** Let $f$ be a function whose domain is a set $A$. The function $f$ is injective if and only if for all $a$ and $b$
>   in $A$, if $f(a) = f(b)$, then a = b; that is, $f(a) = f(b)$ implies $a = b$. 
>   Equivalently, if $a ≠ b$, then $f(a) ≠ f(b)$.
>   [[Injective functions]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function)

you should start with a complete statistic $S(X)$ and then consider whether or not the first property holds for $f(S(X))$ and $f$ injective.

Comment: +1 Putting the two together suggests we ought to worry about whether this "one-to-one function" actually is *measurable*.

Comment: @whuber: isn't it necessary measurable wrt the projected $\sigma$-algebra $f(\mathfrak{S})$?

Comment: Measurability is not part of the definition of injectivity.

Comment: @whuber: I am not stating measurability is mentioned in injectivity or completeness definitions. Just stating the "obvious" that there exists a $\sigma$ algebra that makes any $f$ measurable.